# Bootstrap 3 offset on right not left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

In regards to BS 3 if I wanted just a narrow column of content on the right I might use an offset class of 9 and a column of 3.

However, what if I wanted the reverse and on the left side? Is there a proper way to do this in BS or should I just use my own CSS methods? I was thinking of creating a column of 3 with my content and just an empty column of 9.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Bootstrap rows always contain their floats and create new lines. You don't need to worry about filling blank columns, just make sure they don't add up to more than 12.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-9">
      I'm a right column of 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      I'm a left column of 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      And I'm some content below both columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For a blank column, use Bootstrap's `col-X-pull-Y` classes. For example, to push something of 50% size to the right but leave one column of space to the right (in a 12-column grid as an example): `col-xs-6 pull-right col-xs-pull-1`

Comment: It's on the left because you split the content into different rows manually. And if you remove them and the following content is not 100% wide (i.e. follows some columns of 50% width `col-xs-6`) it will pile wierdly.

Comment: I don't know why this is the accepted answer with so many votes, it does not answer the question, all that has happened here is the col-xs-3 is wrapped by a row, which is why no further content has landed on that same line/row. if there was another col-xs-3 then it would be right next to the 1st col-xs-3 on the same row, so this answer does not answer the question.
The answer by kpull1 achieves the requested result.

Answer (score 83):

I'm using the following simple custom CSS I wrote to achieve this.

```
.col-xs-offset-right-12 {
  margin-right: 100%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-11 {
  margin-right: 91.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-10 {
  margin-right: 83.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-9 {
  margin-right: 75%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-8 {
  margin-right: 66.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-7 {
  margin-right: 58.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-6 {
  margin-right: 50%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-5 {
  margin-right: 41.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-4 {
  margin-right: 33.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-3 {
  margin-right: 25%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-2 {
  margin-right: 16.66666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-1 {
  margin-right: 8.33333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-right-0 {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-offset-right-12 {
    margin-right: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-11 {
    margin-right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-10 {
    margin-right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-9 {
    margin-right: 75%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-8 {
    margin-right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-7 {
    margin-right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-6 {
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-5 {
    margin-right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-4 {
    margin-right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-3 {
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-2 {
    margin-right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-1 {
    margin-right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-offset-right-0 {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-offset-right-12 {
    margin-right: 100%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-11 {
    margin-right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-10 {
    margin-right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-9 {
    margin-right: 75%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-8 {
    margin-right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-7 {
    margin-right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-6 {
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-5 {
    margin-right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-4 {
    margin-right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-3 {
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-2 {
    margin-right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-1 {
    margin-right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-md-offset-right-0 {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-offset-right-12 {
    margin-right: 100%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-11 {
    margin-right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-10 {
    margin-right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-9 {
    margin-right: 75%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-8 {
    margin-right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-7 {
    margin-right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-6 {
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-5 {
    margin-right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-4 {
    margin-right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-3 {
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-2 {
    margin-right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-1 {
    margin-right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .col-lg-offset-right-0 {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hardcoding the percentages is very non-ideal. Additionally, it's possible to change how Bootstrap's grid system works, so you are not guaranteed to have 12 columns. In that instance, this answer fails. You are better off calculating the percentage relative to the number of grid columns.

Comment: bootstrap does the same thing only from the left

Comment: a great workaround! this must be in bootstrap, I never understood why did not they added

Answer (score 18):

```css
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-pull-2">
col-md-10 col-md-pull-2
</div>
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-pull-2">
col-md-10 col-md-pull-2
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

I modified Bootstrap SASS (v3.3.5) based on [Rukshan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501063/293847)

Add this in the end of the `calc-grid-column` mixin in `mixins/_grid-framework.scss`, right below the `$type == offset` if condition.

```
@if ($type == offset-right) {
      .col-#{$class}-offset-right-#{$index} {
          margin-right: percentage(($index / $grid-columns));
      }
  }
```

Modify the `make-grid` mixin in `mixins/_grid-framework.scss` to generate the `offset-right` classes.

```
// Create grid for specific class
@mixin make-grid($class) {
  @include float-grid-columns($class);
  @include loop-grid-columns($grid-columns, $class, width);
  @include loop-grid-columns($grid-columns, $class, pull);
  @include loop-grid-columns($grid-columns, $class, push);
  @include loop-grid-columns($grid-columns, $class, offset);
  @include loop-grid-columns($grid-columns, $class, offset-right);
}
```

You can then use the classes like `col-sm-offset-right-2` and `col-md-offset-right-1`

Comment: +1 for using `percentage` instead of hardcoding the values; this is closer to how Bootstrap internally handles the grid system, plus it allows a variable grid column if the default 12 is undesired.

Answer (score 4):

Since Google seems to like this answer...

If you're looking to match Bootstrap 4's naming convention, i.e. offset-*-#, here's that modification:

```
.offset-right-12 {
  margin-right: 100%;
}
.offset-right-11 {
  margin-right: 91.66666667%;
}
.offset-right-10 {
  margin-right: 83.33333333%;
}
.offset-right-9 {
  margin-right: 75%;
}
.offset-right-8 {
  margin-right: 66.66666667%;
}
.offset-right-7 {
  margin-right: 58.33333333%;
}
.offset-right-6 {
  margin-right: 50%;
}
.offset-right-5 {
  margin-right: 41.66666667%;
}
.offset-right-4 {
  margin-right: 33.33333333%;
}
.offset-right-3 {
  margin-right: 25%;
}
.offset-right-2 {
  margin-right: 16.66666667%;
}
.offset-right-1 {
  margin-right: 8.33333333%;
}
.offset-right-0 {
  margin-right: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .offset-sm-right-12 {
    margin-right: 100%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-11 {
    margin-right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-10 {
    margin-right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-9 {
    margin-right: 75%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-8 {
    margin-right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-7 {
    margin-right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-6 {
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-5 {
    margin-right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-4 {
    margin-right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-3 {
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-2 {
    margin-right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-1 {
    margin-right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-sm-right-0 {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .offset-md-right-12 {
    margin-right: 100%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-11 {
    margin-right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-10 {
    margin-right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-9 {
    margin-right: 75%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-8 {
    margin-right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-7 {
    margin-right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-6 {
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-5 {
    margin-right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-4 {
    margin-right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-3 {
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-2 {
    margin-right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-1 {
    margin-right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-md-right-0 {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .offset-lg-right-12 {
    margin-right: 100%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-11 {
    margin-right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-10 {
    margin-right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-9 {
    margin-right: 75%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-8 {
    margin-right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-7 {
    margin-right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-6 {
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-5 {
    margin-right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-4 {
    margin-right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-3 {
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-2 {
    margin-right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-1 {
    margin-right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-lg-right-0 {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .offset-xl-right-12 {
    margin-right: 100%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-11 {
    margin-right: 91.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-10 {
    margin-right: 83.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-9 {
    margin-right: 75%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-8 {
    margin-right: 66.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-7 {
    margin-right: 58.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-6 {
    margin-right: 50%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-5 {
    margin-right: 41.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-4 {
    margin-right: 33.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-3 {
    margin-right: 25%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-2 {
    margin-right: 16.66666667%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-1 {
    margin-right: 8.33333333%;
  }
  .offset-xl-right-0 {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to combine multiple classes (`col-*-offset-*` for left-margin and `col-*-pull-*` to pull it right)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-9">
      I'm a right column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      We're
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      using the
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      whole row
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-9 col-xs-pull-9">
      I'm a left column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      We're
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      four columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      using the
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      whole row
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So you don't need to separate it manually into different rows.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [WeNeigh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31110011/1809033)! here is a LESS example

```
.col-offset-right(@i, @type) when (@i >= 0) {
    .col-@{type}-offset-right-@{i} {
        margin-right: percentage((@i / @grid-columns));
    }
    .col-offset-right(@i - 1, @type);
};
.col-offset-right(@grid-columns, xs);
.col-offset-right(@grid-columns, sm);
.col-offset-right(@grid-columns, md);
.col-offset-right(@grid-columns, lg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same solution than Rukshan but in sass (in order to keep your grid configuration) for special case that don't work with Ross Allen solution (when you can't have a parent div.row)

```
@mixin make-grid-offset-right($class) {
    @for $index from 0 through $grid-columns {
        .col-#{$class}-offset-right-#{$index} {
            margin-right: percentage(($index / $grid-columns));
        }
    }
}

@include make-grid-offset-right(xs);

@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) {
  @include make-grid-offset-right(sm);
}

@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) {
  @include make-grid-offset-right(md);
}

@media (min-width: $screen-lg-min) {
  @include make-grid-offset-right(lg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="row col-xs-12">            
            <nav class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-7" aria-label="Page navigation">
                <ul class="pagination mt-0">                   
                    <li class="page-item">                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" asp-for="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-controls="order-listing" />

                                <div class="input-group-prepend bg-info">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="input-group-text bg-transparent">                                   
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                   
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 SASS solution:

```
@mixin make-col-offset-end($size, $columns: $grid-columns) {
  $num: divide($size, $columns);
  margin-right: if($num == 0, 0, percentage($num));
}

@mixin make-grid-offset-end($columns: $grid-columns, $gutter: $grid-gutter-width, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $breakpoint in map-keys($breakpoints) {
    $infix: breakpoint-infix($breakpoint, $breakpoints);

    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
      @if $columns > 0 {
        // `$columns - 1` because offsetting by the width of an entire row isn't possible
        @for $i from 0 through ($columns - 1) {
          @if not ($infix == "" and $i == 0) { // Avoid emitting useless .offset-0
            .offset-end#{$infix}-#{$i} {
              @include make-col-offset-end($i, $columns);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@include make-grid-offset-end();
```

This will give you all of the classes `offset` already has, but with `offset-end` (e.g. `offset-end-md-2`)