# Right to left columns using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

I have a row with a dynamic count of columns that is generated in JADE based on data fetched 
from the database.
Items are image and the count of them can be 0 and can be a large number (max 100).

The .row is inside of a frame and I want to be able to populate the images in a right-to-left orders. Meaning, first image is at the top-right corner, second one is to the left of the first. each image uses col-md-2 so after 6 images the 7th should be under the first one.

Right now, when generating the columns the first one is at the top-left corner.. as it's the default.

Any way to change that?

Tried using col-md-offset-X and it's only effecting the first line of images (because it's a single row)

```
Current:
--------------
| x  x  x  x |
| x  x       |
--------------

How it should be:
--------------
| x  x  x  x |
|       x  x |
--------------
```

Comment: hm, maybe you have some mockup how it should look like ?

Comment: have you tried to override `.col-md-2`  with `float: right` ?

Comment: @Evgeniy , Added a mockup.

Comment: Tried adding float: right; but it causes the whole row to get out of it's container from the right side.

Comment: is this close to your expectation - http://jsfiddle.net/okkf3kjh/ ?

Comment: Exactly! Added pull-right the the div to make if float: right; and it looks good. The last comment effect was caused by a different issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To reach your goal you have to change floating in `.col-md-2`. If necessary use `!important`.

```
.col-md-2 {
    float: right !important;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/okkf3kjh/)

Comment: you can either use 'pull-right' class name that does the same job but the problem is when you resize the screen, the elements still stick together instead of getting over each other. what I did is this in my style.css:

/* define a class with empty properties */
.col-rtl{}

/*then create a media query and put the float in there */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
    .col-rtl{
        float:right;
    }
}

Now when you resize the screen, the elements the follow instructions of bootstrap.css, only when the screen is 992px they float right.

Comment: u can add into bootstrap.css `.row>div{
    float: right !important;
}` to apply it to all columns.

Answer (score 6):

In bootstrap 4, if you want the columns of a row to start from right to left and you set multiple column classes on a div, I suggest an easy solution by adding `justify-content-end` to the row enclosing the columns.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="row justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
  First col text
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
  First col text
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
  Second col text
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">
  Third col text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flex component of bootstrap to achieve this.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
  <div class="bg-info">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="bg-info">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="bg-info">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that available in Bootstrap 3?

Comment: @Anthony If I am not wrong Boostrap3 uses floats unlike Boostrap4 which uses flexbox. checkout this thread for BS3 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533969/bootstrap-3-offset-on-right-not-left/20536713

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 4 U can use flex-row-reverse class
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how automated your system is in this case, the question doesn't really tell me if you're using some sort of a image gallery, but if it's not, if it's all manually added content, why not create **empty columns** to justify the last items.

Always have a full row, but just use something like `&nbsp;` at the very first ones that you are leaving blank.

Comment: It is a kind of image gallery.. something like facebook post with a sub image gallery..

Comment: Ah, then this answer is not in any way useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `flex-direction` property for sorting the columns from right to left/ RTL.

Set it on the 'row` container:

```
flex-direction: row-reverse;
```

Or set Bootstrap class to a container:

```
class="flex-row-reverse"
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about the bootsrap, But here is the generic way of approach to solve your problem.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
    <div>eleven</div>
    <div>twelve</div>
    <div>thirteen</div>
    <div>fourteen</div>
    <div>fifteen</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main div {
    float: right;
    width: 70px;
}
.main div:nth-child(6n + 7) {
    clear: right;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q9zh8508/1/)